# AS3: Sort array descending while keeping strings in correct order

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm not sure whether there is a simply answer to this but I am assuming there isn't, hence I'm here.

Basically, I want to run a very simple high score table which keeps track of the high scores of a game, but also displays the correct names beside each scores.

This is all easy but I want to be able to do this with just the one array.

For example, I have this code:

```
var d:Array;
var e:Array;
d = "827-Harry".split("-");
d.push("918-John".split("-"));
trace(d)
```

Which correctly results this trace:

827,Harry,918,John

My question is, how can I use Array.sort() (or similar) in such a way that the following is produced:

d = 918, John, 827, Harry

It can't be specific to this example. That is, it needs to work with custom names and dynamic scores.

Cheers in advance!
Harry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create an associative array and use [sortOn()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29):

```
var highscores:Array = new Array();
highscores.push({score: 827, player: "John"});
highscores.push({score: 918, player: "Harry"});
highscores.sortOn("score", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);

for (var i:int = 0; i < highscores.length; i++)
{
    trace(highscores[i].score, highscores[i].player);
}
```

Comment: Didn't expect this to be so easy - strangely, I've not seen arrays used like this before. Thanks for showing me something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't recommend you store your high scores like that but I don't know your reasons so here's exactly how to do what you want.

```
public function sortArray(arrUnsorted:Array):Array
{
    var arrLocal:Array = new Array();
    var arrSorted:Array = new Array();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < arrUnsorted.length; i += 2)
    {
        arrLocal.push( { score:int(arrUnsorted[i]), name:arrUnsorted[i + 1] } );
    }

    arrLocal.sortOn("score", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC)

    for each(var obj:Object in arrLocal)
    {
        arrSorted.push(String(obj.score), obj.name);
    }

    return arrSorted;
}
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
var arrUnsorted:Array = ["827", "Harry", "918", "John"];
var arrSorted:Array = sortArray(arrUnsorted);

trace(arrSorted); // 918,John,827,Harry
```

Hope this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the help - may I ask what downfalls there are to sorting the array in this way?

Comment: Well running two loops every time you need to sort the array can be processor intensive depending on how many scores you are sorting. Although computers today along with the optimisations in AVM2 _(the virtual machine that runs the AS3 code)_ mean you should be able to sort thousands of scores without any noticeable impact. So if this is how you want to handle your scores, it should work fine so long as you don't intend to sort millions etc. The great thing about TheDarkIn1978's solution is you're only storing and sorting a single `Array` object.

Comment: Okay, many thanks for the detailed response :) I don't think my app will really reach into the thousands let alone millions, so it looks like I should be able to stick with this method :) Cheers again mate!